# disable automatic defect logging in ALM

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I am unable to handle the "defects" in ALM. How to disable the automatic "defects" logging in ALM?

Answer (score 0):

To disable the defect logging, the following property needs to be set in init.properties file.

test.alm.run= true

If defect logging is disabled, the step level status will be updated as per execution  in HP ALM and the test execution status for the test run will be logged as 'Not Completed'.

If test.alm.run=true, then testcase final status will not be updated automatically, if you want auto updation of status please keep test.alm.run= false.